# Android Progress Dialog Gravity Issue

Tags: android, progressdialog, customdialog

Below is my code for custom progress bar. I have issue with just Gravity.

Here is the code.

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(LandingPageActivity.this, R.style.AppBaseTheme);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.anim.progressbar));
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


            dialog.show();
```

Style.xml

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
        <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>

    </style>


style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
        <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerBright">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerDark">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:fullBright">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:fullDark">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:topBright">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:topDark">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>

    </style>
```

animation file code

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim00" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim01" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim02" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim04" android:duration="150" />

</animation-list>
```

I am able to show progress bar correctly but gravity is taking Left Top by default.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: where have you assigned the `CustomAlertDialogStyle` ?

Comment: If you have applied gravity in your custom style then why you have applied second time to ur progress bar using this `dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`?

Comment: I have tried both. Nothing is happening. Gravity still there at top left.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I had refer that question only but still not working :(

Comment: @MayuriRuparel In that no gravity is set while you are created ProgressDialog it will show in centre of Window.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Just checked with that. Same issue. Thanks for helping

Comment: @MayuriRuparel This will show your Proress Dialog in center of your window with custom style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution:

You need to make one custom style in `style.xml` file which has a `android:Theme.Holo.Dialog` theme. Like,

#### CustomProgress

```
  <style name="CustomProgress" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

and add your `CustomAlertDialogStyle` to your `CustomProgress` style instead of `AppBaseTheme`.

Now use your custom style for your `ProgressDialog`

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(LandingPageActivity.this, R.style.CustomProgress);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked and gravity set to center but background was issue. So I made this change to your code.  dialog = new ProgressDialog(LandingPageActivity.this, R.style.MyTheme);

Answer (score 1):

Add following code above dialog.show().Hope it may work..

```
                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

                wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

                window.setAttributes(wlp);
                dialog.show();
```